# Implementation of the cyclotomic numbers

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, cyclotomic-fields

In the [Haskell library Cyclotomic](https://github.com/walck/cyclotomic), a cyclotomic number is "encoded" as an integer called the *order* and a map from the integers to the rationals called the *coefficients*. Would you have an explanation or/and a reference of this way to implement the cyclotomic numbers? I started to port the Haskell code to the R language but even though I roughly understand the code, I don't understand the idea. I would prefer to understand how it works rather than blindly translating the code.

One can find these comments in the Haskell code:

- Step 1 of cyclotomic is gcd reduction.
- Step 2 of cyclotomic is reduction to a rational if possible.
- Step 3 of cyclotomic is base reduction.

Comment: I don't understand your Haskell code but if it implements $K=\bigcup_{n\ge 1} \Bbb{Q}(\zeta_n)$ then it should be implemented as $\Bbb{Q}[\{ \zeta_{p^e}, p^e \text{ prime power}\}]$ as the minimal polynomial of each $\zeta_{p^e}$ is known without additional calculation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general:

Given some separable polynomial $p\in\mathbb{Q}[X]$. In this case, a [cyclotomic polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial).

Considering the field $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(p)$. In our case, a [cyclotomic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_field)

The elements $x\in\mathbb{Q}[X]/(p)$ of this field can be expressed uniquely as $x=x_0+x_1X+x_2X^2+x_3X^3+\cdots+x_{\mathrm{deg}p-1}X^{\mathrm{deg}p-1}$ where the $x_i$ are elements of $\mathbb{Q}$.

In the general case, you should be careful if not all zeroes of $p$ are in $\mathbb{Q}[X]/(p)$, because then the embedding into $\mathbb{C}$ is more problematic. But when $p$ is a cyclotomic polynomial, all zeroes do appear in this field.

When you want a not-exact implementation, you can take the morphism $\mathbb{Q}[X]/\Phi_n\to\mathbb{C}$ generated by $X\mapsto \zeta_n$ where $\zeta_n=e^{\frac{2\pi i}n}$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, so you take the coefficients $(x_0,x_1,x_2,\dots,x_{\mathrm{deg}\Phi_n-1})$ and send them to $x_0\cdot1+x_1\cdot \zeta_n+x_2\cdot\zeta_n^2+\cdots+x_{\mathrm{deg}\Phi_n-1}\cdot \zeta_n^{\mathrm{deg}\Phi_n-1}$.

This is not-exact because the exponents $e^{\frac{2k\pi i}n}$ cannot trivially be implemented with infinite precision.

The order in this case is the number of the cyclotomic polynomial $p$. That is, when the order is $n$, the "number" $\zeta_n=0+1\cdot X+0\cdot X^2+\dots+0\cdot X^{\mathrm{deg}\Phi_n-1}$ is exactly a primitive $n$th root of unity.

Comment: Ok thanks, so the map (named "coefficients") in the Haskell implementation sends an exponent to a $x_i$, if I correctly understand. In fact a map is almost like a list of tuples $(k, r)$ which represent $rX^k$.

Comment: Would you know if the book "Cyclotomic fields" by Serge Lang is easy to read? I *had* a good level in mathematics but I didn't practice algebra for more than 20 years.

Comment: "In fact a map is almost like a list of tuples $(k,r)$ which represent $rX^k$": 

Set-theoretically, yes, a function is a list of tuples where $(a,b)\in f$ means $f(a)=b$. But in our case, you should think of the coefficients $x_i$ as a map $\mathbb{N}\to\mathbb{Q}$ that sends $n$ to $x_n$.

Comment: "Would you know if the book "Cyclotomic fields" by Serge Lang is easy to read?" I have never read it. Judging by its title, it will probably cover much more than you need here; you probably only need the first few chapters. I leaned from [this](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/algebra3.pdf) and [this](https://websites.math.leidenuniv.nl/algebra/algebra2.pdf) book (in Dutch ), chapters 13.9 and 24 should cover most of what you need here. You can of course ask a new question for book references.